# What purpose does os.path.dirname() serve?

Tags: python

I was looking at some Flask code,bur I am struggling to understand how dirname works.
For example

```
>>> os.path.abspath('./')
```

returns

```
'/home/mm'
```

as expected.

```
>>> dirname('./')
'.'
```

Why doesn't `dirname` give the same output?

Comment: What was unclear in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname)?

Comment: Because the two functions have different specifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname) says about `os.path.dirname`:

> Return the directory name of pathname path. This is the first element of the pair returned by passing path to the function split().

So it returns the name of the directory of the path passed.
That is `os.path.dirname("/a/b/c")` returns `"/a/b"`.

This function is complemented by [`os.path.basename`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename), which returns the name of the file. To continue with the same example, `os.path.basename("/a/b/c")` will return `"c"`.

---

On the other hand, `os.path.abspath` is just something completely different, as explained once again in [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath):

> Return a normalized absolutized version of the pathname path. On most platforms, this is equivalent to calling the function normpath() as follows: normpath(join(os.getcwd(), path)).

So `os.path.abspath("./a/b/c")` will return the absolute version of `"./a/b/c"`, that is, relatively to the root of the filesystem.
If you're in your homedir, it will give you `"/home/username/a/b/c"`.